# AppleScript click Ui Element with modifier keys

Tags: applescript, ui

I want to click an Ui Element button with modifier keys pressed.

Here is my code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pro Tools"
        tell (1st window whose title contains "Edit: ")
            tell table "Group List"
                tell row 2
                    tell UI element 2

                        click       

                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I tried adding key down (option) and key up (option) between the click lines, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Basic vanilla **AppleScript** does not have a provision to preform a `key down` and `mouse click` simultaneously. You could try using a third-party utility like https://www.bluem.net/jump/cliclick/ wrapped in a `do shell script` _command_. You'd have to programmatically determine the position of `UI element 2` to then click on it with `cliclick`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have **Pro Tools**, so I can only offer some information that may help you.

First I have to say that **UI Scripting** can be kludgy and may not always work consistently depending on how its *coded* and the `UI element` being targeted. It's always better if one can find a way to do something without resorting to **UI Scripting** first.

As I originally said to you in a comment... Basic vanilla **AppleScript** does not have a provision to preform a `key down` and `mouse click` simultaneously. You could try using a third-party utility like [**cliclick**](https://www.bluem.net/jump/cliclick/) wrapped in a `do shell script` *command*. You'd have to programmatically determine the position of `UI element 2` to then click on it with `cliclick`.

Without **Pro Tools**, I'm going to use **Safari** as an example, and the **Show sidebar** `UI element` on its **Toolbar** in conjunction with `cliclick` in a `do shell script` *command*.

The purpose of following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is to demonstrate how to programmatically get the `position` and `size` of the target `UI element`, in order to calculate where to *click*. It also assumes that **Safari** is already running with a standard window opened to, e.g., this question you posted.

```
activate application "Safari"
delay 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set ps to {position, size} ¬
        of UI element 2 ¬
        of toolbar 1 ¬
        of window 1 ¬
        of application process "Safari"

set p to item 1 of ps
set s to item 2 of ps

set x to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) / 2 as integer
set y to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) / 2 as integer

do shell script "$HOME/bin/cliclick c:" & x & "," & y
```

<sup>• Change `$HOME/bin/cliclick` as appropriate to: `/path/to/cliclick`</sup>

When run in **Script Editor**, this clicked the **Show sidebar** `UI element` on the **Toolbar** in **Safari**.

Now I know you said you want to click with the **option** *key* down, however for a practical example I'm going to modify the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, to *control-click* to the right of the **Show sidebar** `UI element` on the **Toolbar** in **Safari**, which will pop-up the **Customize Toolbar…** menu.

**Change:**

```
set x to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) / 2 as integer
```

**To:**

```
set x to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) * 2 as integer
```

- <sup>Instead of dividing the `x` *axis size* by two to get the center of the target `UI element` on its `x` *axis* , we'll multiply its `x` *axis size* by two so it will click on the **Toolbar** itself.</sup>

**Also Change:**

```
do shell script "$HOME/bin/cliclick c:" & x & "," & y
```

**To:**

```
do shell script "$HOME/bin/cliclick kd:ctrl c:" & x & "," & y & " ku:ctrl"
```

Now when run in **Script Editor**, this *control-clicked* to the right of the **Show sidebar** `UI element` on the **Toolbar** in **Safari** and popped-up the **Customize Toolbar…** menu.

---

With all of this in mind, maybe the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will work for you, however remember it's untested as I do not have **Pro Tools** and may require you to rework the `tell application "System Events" ...` *statement*:

```
activate application "Pro Tools"
delay 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set ps to {position, size} ¬
        of UI element 2 ¬
        of row 2 ¬
        of table "Group List" ¬
        of (first window whose title contains "Edit: ") ¬
        of application process "Pro Tools"

set p to item 1 of ps
set s to item 2 of ps

set x to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) / 2 as integer
set y to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) / 2 as integer

do shell script "$HOME/bin/cliclick -r kd:alt c:" & x & "," & y & " ku:alt"
```

<sup>• Change `$HOME/bin/cliclick` as appropriate to: `/path/to/cliclick`</sup>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use with **Safari** and `cliclick` was tested and worked as presented in **macOS Catalina**.</sub>

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of `cliclick`, just a satisfied user of the product.</sub>